# Angular routeProvider not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am following a basic tutorial to learn Angular Js [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ILQOFAgaXE)

To cut in short i am creating a main page(index.html) and another page(login.html). I wrote the basic html but for instance i`ll share the important lines that effects Angular.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []).config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
 });


$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo : '/login'});

});

 app.controller('LoginController', function(){
      // To be left blank at the moment.
});
```

**Login.html**

```
<div id="login" class="row">
<div class="large-3 large-offset-3">
    <form>
        <fieldset class="radius">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-6 columns">
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
                </div>
                <div class="large-6 columns">
                    <input type="password" name="username" placeholder="password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <button type="submit" class="button large expand radius">Log In</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12">
        <h1> Introduction to Angular Js</h1>
        <div id="view" ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** When i try to open localhost/angular it shows me index.html and when i try doing localhost/angular/login it says "404 Not Found"

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the url: localhost/angular/#/login

Comment: It is redirecting me back to localhost/angular which is because of .otherwise may be ... but it is now even showing the view for login.html which it should being a one page app no?

Comment: do you have an htaccess ? try to join Try accessing the url: localhost/angular#/login

Comment: as i said it is redirecting me to main page again ... may be because of $routeProvider.otherwise()

Answer (score 0):

add the file angular.route.js and this in your module

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute'])
```

and don't forget it, it can be useful

`$routeProvider.otherwise({
redirectTo: '/'
});`

Comment: I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: you do not have route define for /

Comment: I added angular-route.js. Now let me tell you the hierarchy. I have index.html and login.html.

when i open localhost/angular - it shows me index.html
now i want to show login.html when i open localhost/angular/login

I dont know what wrong i am doing.